# Using PHP how can I count how many items of one mySQL result exists in the second?

Tags: php, mysql

Using PHP I select from mySQL table one some rows containing the column hash for a specific day. All these rows are unique. Also, from table two I do the same thing, I get the column hash for a specific day, again uniques.

Using PHP, how can I know how many hash from table one are found on table two?

```
$first_visits=mysql_query("SELECT hash AS first_visit
FROM audience
WHERE DATE( TIMESTAMP ) =  '2016-03-28'");

$visits=mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT (
hash
) AS visit
FROM behaviour
WHERE DATE( TIMESTAMP ) =  '2016-03-29'");
```

Now i want to compare the first group with the second group to find out how many of the first exists in the second USING PHP

Comment: yon need just a count, or exact hash strings?

Comment: would you like "`Using PHP`" pure PHP solution? Im wondering why is everyone answering in SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with single SQL query by joining both tables using `hash` column:

If you need just a count:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT v.`hash`) hashCount
FROM
    first_visit v
    INNER JOIN behaviour b ON v.`hash` = b.`hash`
WHERE
    DATE(v.`timestamp`) = '2016-03-28'
    AND DATE(b.`timestamp`) = '2016-03-29'
```

If you need exact hash strings, then select them:

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT v.`hash`
FROM
    first_visit v
    INNER JOIN behaviour b ON v.`hash` = b.`hash`
WHERE
    DATE(v.`timestamp`) = '2016-03-28'
    AND DATE(b.`timestamp`) = '2016-03-29'
```

Using PHP, just fetch the SQL result.

But. In order to achieve better performance result, I would suggest to avoid usage of `DATE()` over a column in WHERE clause, but to use `BETWEEN` instead, i.e. to change WHERE clauses as follow:

```
WHERE
    v.`timestamp` BETWEEN '2016-03-28 00:00:00' AND '2016-03-28 23:59:59'
    AND b.`timestamp` BETWEEN '2016-03-29 00:00:00' AND '2016-03-29 23:59:59'
```

This will allow you to use indexes on both `timestamp` columns.

Comment: Hi thank you for this solution and your valuable info. I will test it now.
I didn't know about the date performance. Because I have a really huge table and performance on this specific thing is an issue. Shall I use `between` or to use `<= >=` instead?

Comment: Regarding BETWEEN and <=> is almost the same, the important point here is not to use `WHERE DATE(timestamp)`

Comment: I have accepted your solution. Thank you. Just please give me your 2 cents, in regards of performance, shall i use `IN` or your solution with `JOIN` ?

Comment: As I've commented on other post here, `IN` is most unlikely option. Is better to avoid as much you can subqueries or (if not possible) to use `EXISTS` instead of `IN`. So yes, `JOIN` is better option in all cases because then you have only one query in total.

Comment: Thanks. Suppose that the timestamp range of the behaviour table is changed to 29-31 (3 days). If a hash from first_visit is found on behaviour 29 and 30, will it return 1 or 2? My aim is to return 1.

Comment: Yes, will return 1 as you make SELECT DISTINCT of first_visit hashes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107849/discussion-between-mitkosoft-and-villoui).

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to fetch your queries to array and use array_intersec(array1, array2) to have an array with the common result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

`SELECT DISTINCT (hash) AS visit
FROM behaviour
WHERE DATE( TIMESTAMP ) =  '2016-03-29' and 
hash in (SELECT hash AS first_visit FROM audience WHERE DATE( TIMESTAMP ) =  '2016-03-28')`

Comment: Using IN clause (instead of EXISTS which is much faster) combined with subquery will affect a lot the performance as MySQL must materialize this subquery. In case of big amout of data, this query will be quite slow.

Answer (score -1):

try this. save first result in first_visits_rows, and on fetching second query compare to find matches

```
$first_visits = mysql_query("SELECT hash AS first_visit FROM audience  

WHERE DATE( TIMESTAMP ) =  '2016-03-28'");
$first_visits_rows = [];
while ($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($first_visits)) {
    $first_visits_rows[$r["hash"]] = $r["hash"];
}

$visits = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT (hash) AS visit FROM behaviour WHERE DATE( TIMESTAMP ) =  '2016-03-29'");
$matches = 0;
while ($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($visits)) {
    if (isset($first_visits_rows[$r["hash"]])) {
        $matches++;
    }
}
echo $matches;
```

or you can olso use mysql join to directly get matches

```
$first_visits=mysql_query("SELECT count(hash) as matches from first_visit as f join behaviour as b on f.hash=b.hash");
$r = mysql_query($first_visits);
$matches = $r["matches"];
```

Comment: No. I select hash from each table so as to compare them

Comment: The guy is looking for number of matching hash records from first table into second one...

Comment: I get this: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in `$first_visits_rows = [];`

Comment: maybe you have old php version. change it to `$first_visits_rows = array();`